# Using the LinQ zip function over a single array

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to create a list of {startLocation, endLocation} from a list of locations and an initial and final startLocation. Wondering if zip is a function to use.

Input:

```
Start: denver
ListOfStops: houston, austin, tucson
Final: denver
```

output:

```
leg[0]: denver-> houston
leg[1]: houston->austin
leg[2]: austin->tucson
leg[3]: tucson->denver
```

Is it possible do this with one linq statment?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is the `Aggregate()` LINQ method. I'll see if I can come up with one that works.

Answer (score 2):

With some small helper functions for dealing with single items in LINQ

```
public static class Ext {
    public static IEnumerable<T> Prepend<T>(this IEnumerable<T> rest, params T[] first) => first.Concat(rest);
    public static IEnumerable<T> Append<T>(this IEnumerable<T> rest, params T[] last) => rest.Concat(last);
}
```

then you can use `Zip` as you suggested:

```
var Start = "denver";
var ListOfStops = new[] { "houston", "austin", "tucson" };
var Final = "denver";

var ans = ListOfStops.Prepend(Start).Append(Final).Zip(ListOfStops.Append(Final), (l,r) => (l,r)).Dump();
```

Comment: I like how you use `params` to convert the single item into an array.

Comment: ANd it also allows you to `Prepend`/`Append` multiple items :)

Answer (score 0):

Not the prettiest, but this works:

```
string start = "denver";
string[] stops = "houston, austin, tucson".Split(new[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
string final = "denver";

var legs = stops.Concat(new[] { final })
    .Aggregate(new List<Tuple<string, string>>(), (list, val) =>
        {
            list.Add(Tuple.Create(list.Any() ? list.Last().Item2 : start, val));
            return list;
        })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `Aggregate` when you're not actually aggregating things.  If you want to have a foreach loop then just use a foreach loop, rather than abusing `Aggregate` to write a `foreach` loop in a convoluted way.

Comment: I have something close to that, that works.  I think there has to be a more elegant way to do this

Comment: @Servy I agree, but OP asked for a single LINQ statement, so that's what I gave them.

Comment: @Pepper The more elegant way is a loop. You could also create an iterator method.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why did you create `stops` in such a convoluted way?

Comment: @NetMage To match OP's starting string.

Comment: @Servy, The goal was to create a list, and he aggregates that list by added one item to it for each item in the initial collection.  Which is exactly what Aggregate is designed for.  I'm more bothered by the `list.Last().Item2`  (But I'd handle that with an external closured variable, which would offend more people).

Comment: @JamesCurran Aggregate is designed to compute a *new* item, that incorporates a given item into the accumulated results of all of the items that came before it.  It's not designed to mutate an existing item.  At that point you're getting nothing at all out of the method other than a `foreach`, and you're having to actively fight the method itself to do even that.

Comment: @Servy, But his code is *not* mutating an existing item.  The list is create by the first parameter to Aggregate, and that list is build upon.  That list (as a single unit) is the aggregation of the items in the array.

Comment: @JamesCurran It's not mutating an existing item in the list, the "aggregation" items are mutating an existing list, rather than creating a new accumulator object, which is what it's supposed to be doing.  The whole design of linq is that all of the operations are side effect free, and that they perform *queries*, not *mutation* of things.  This is *contrary* to that design, and results in an answer that's *fighting* the method, and is *more difficult* than just using a `foreach`.  You gain nothing, and lose something, making this a bad solution.

Comment: @Servy To be fair, this solution *is* side effect free. Any changes are isolated in the Aggregate() call. Also, it performs a query. While I agree that this is a poor version of a foreach, it does exactly what the OP asked for and meets your LINQ "requirements". Would I use this in production code? Of course not. Does it answer the OP's question? IMO it does.

Comment: @itsme86 Why would you suggest something as a solution that you don't think is a good solution, and wouldn't actually recommend anyone use?  It's a lose-lose situation.  Either they realize it's a bad solution, and you just wasted their time, or worse, they use your bad solution instead of a *good* solution.  Just post a *good* solution instead.

Comment: @Servy This is why multiple people can answer a question. In my mind, it's valuable to let people explore the design they already have in mind. If you disagree, that's fine; you have the rep to downvote those answers. But until the site's guidelines say I shouldn't, I'll keep providing answers that actually answer the OP's question and help them learn and discover things at a pace that works for them. It's akin to letting children make mistakes: https://www.psychologies.co.uk/let-your-child-make-mistakes

Comment: @itsme86 Letting someone make a mistake, and not giving someone a solution while they're experimenting on their own, is *very* different from intentionally giving someone bad advice just to watch them fail.  Intentionally giving people bad advice is just being mean.

Answer (score -1):

My variation on @itsme86's answer:

```
string start = "denver";
string[] stops = "houston, austin, tucson".Split(new[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
string final = "denver";

var last = start;
var legs = stops.Concat(new[] { final })
    .Aggregate(new List<Tuple<string, string>>(), (list, val) =>
        {
            list.Add(Tuple.Create(last, val));
            last = val;
            return list;
        });
```

Comment: And it has all of the same problems as that answer, and then some.  If you want to write a `foreach`, then *write a `foreach`*.  Don't write an `Aggregate` call that doesn't actually use the functionality of `Aggregate` to do the aggregation.